# How to specify zlib inflation size

Tags: c, zlib

Is there a way to specify a certain number of inflated clear text in zlib? The sample code zpipe.c reads of size CHUNK (16384 bytes) but I do not see where to specify an inflated size. For example, if I only want to read the first 10 bytes before determining if I want to continue the inflation. Is that possible?

Updating question per request:

I am parsing out some zlib deflated content, which has a header. The header determines the type of content (binary or otherwise). In some cases, I just want to deflate the header. At other times, I need to deflate the entire thing. I was wondering if I could write a deflation function that will return X bytes of inflated text, irrespective of the count of deflated text.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You should elaborate with an example of what you imagine doing.

Comment: I am parsing out some zlib deflated content, which has a header. The header determines the type of content (binary or otherwise). In some cases, I just want to deflate the header. At other times, I need to deflate the entire thing.
I was wondering if I could write a deflation function that will return X bytes of inflated text, irrespective of the count of deflated text.

I hope this is more clear (I can update the question if need be) - Also, thank you for your hard work on zlib. We appreciate it, and I am honored to receive a comment from you.

Comment: Please edit that into the question, not leave it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `avail_out` to *n*, then `inflate()` will return at most *n* bytes of uncompressed data.